# How to get actual Pixel Color value from PIL.ImageGrab.grab() in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to take a Pixel color value from the screen in Python

This is the example i'm doing to get the pixel at the position x=30 and y=30 on screen

```
def takePixel() :
    rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[30,30]
```

How do i print out and store the actual pixel color value from this ?

Comment: Did you print out that `rgb` value?

Answer (score 1):

`ImageGrab.grab` returns a `PIL.Image` object, which has a `getpixel` method.

```
def takePixel():
    rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().getpixel(30,30)
    return rgb
print(takePixel())
```